# Django unresolved importing in Eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:32:14) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 1, 'final', 0)
```

Hey I am using Eclipse with PyDev. My OS is Ubuntu 13.04 and I have installed both python 2.7 and python 3.3. I installed django using pip and pip3 for both python verions. I can use django module outside Eclipse but when I import Django in eclipse, it says

```
No module named 'Django'
```

I already looked for an answer on the internet for few hours now. I think my PYTHONPATH includes django location.

Here's the PYTHONPATH in Eclipse:
[image]

PS. I just discovered that I can "import Django" in Python projects, but I cannot "import Django" in Django projects in Eclipse. o.O

Comment: not sure but should it not be ">> import django" .. ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with ubuntu 12.04 + eclipse 3.7.2 + django 1.3.1.
In my case django was installed in "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django".

I tried to do almost as same as yours and failed.
But I have succeeded to import django by doing followings.

1. Remove ".../dist-packages/django" from PYTHONPATH
2. Click on apply (I am not an expert but I've read eclipse is caching somewhere)
3. Add ".../dist-packages" intead
4. Click on apply
5. Create an Pydev project and try to import django
   -> it get imported in my case.
6. Crate an Django project
   -> All relevant files as created as you run "django-admin startproject XXX"

I know this is an old question by I post this for myself too.