# "from . import views": Unresolved import

Tags: python, django, eclipse, django-views, pydev

I'm following the `Django 1.8 tutorial`. In my project `mysite`, there is a source folder `polls`. In the folder there is `views.py` module where a `index` function is defined. And there is a `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This is what the tutorial suggests, and Django works well with the codes. However `Eclipse (PyDev)` complains of `unresolved imports` for `views`. If I remove `from . import views` and use auto-correction function, **PyDev** would recommend `import views`, now Django complains that "**the name views is not defined**". I tried with and without `__init__.py` in the folder, both give the same results.

I am using the latest version for both **Django (1.8)** and **PyDev (4.2)**.

Thanks!

Comment: try the following: from polls import views

Comment: "from polls import views" is the same as "from . import views": they work for Django, but PyDev complains of unresolved import.

Comment: I know they're the same but at times it works away or the other

Comment: Thanks! I've tried both and they work the same way in this case.

Comment: Try and check this, they seem to be related to your problem. http://iswwwup.com/t/c3203194315f/unresolved-import-in-pydev-eclipse-even-if-path-is-in-global-pythonpat.html and http://iswwwup.com/t/ed840ca2d85d/python-unresolved-import-error-eclipse-pydev.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644511/django-unresolved-importing-in-eclipse hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, mkwilfreid, for the hints! I've solved the problem and posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project was created with the **PyDev** wizard as a **Django project**. When it was  created, the folder `polls` is not a source folder. As a result, no code analysis was performed. So I changed the folder `polls` (which is inside the project folder `mysite`) to a source folder. Now the code was analyzed and `unresolved import` error was raised.

The fix is to change `polls` back to a normal folder (removed from **PYTHONPATH**), and instead set the top-level project folder `mysite` as a source folder. Now both **PyDev** and **Django** work well.

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

what you need is to change the. with your parent folder. that's what I did to solve my problem. for example the folder of my project is called blog so I made
*Do this* : **from blog import views** instead of **from . import views**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```